# Concat two mp3 file in byte array in Java

Tags: arrays, byte, mp3, concatenation

I have two byte arrays, both write from mp3 file:
`[B@a7105508` and `[B@a70e85e0`. 
And my question is, how to merge the byte arrays into one byte array and convert to one mp3 file. Because final byte arr = [B@a7105508+[B@a70e85e0 maybe make some error with header file. I known file = header+data. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: What programming language are you doing this with?

Comment: I use Android programming language